# Is it efficient to use SQL functions on the left-hand side of SELECT commands?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

I'm designing a C# program using .NET and Windows Forms. At one point I need to open a form that contains a DataGridView object and a TextBox. The DataGridView object is to be fed with the input on the TextBox and show real-time matches from the database.

To accomplish this, I've been using the simple SQL Query that follows:

```
SqlCommand cmd = "SELECT name,document_no FROM clients WHERE LEFT(name, " + textboxname.Text.Len + ") = '" textboxname.Text + "'";
```

It works for now, while my database contains about a dozen of rows, but is it efficient for large-sized (2k+ entries) databases?

Comment: Also, don't forget to sanitize your `textboxname.Text` to avoid this: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: I've seen more of little bobby in the last 2 weeks than in the previous 2 years.  And it never grows old :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you're taking won't be efficient - at least, not if there's an index on the name column (if there is no such index then expect poor performance whatever you do).  Typically, any function called in a WHERE clause where one or more of the parameters are columns is going to defeat any attempts of the query optimizer to use indexes on those columns.

Much better is:

```
SELECT name,document_no FROM clients WHERE name LIKE 'yourtextboxtexthere%'
```

...which will have a good chance of using the index on name.

Comment: Not quite true.  Some queries obfuscate certain properties of the data from the optimisation engine, some don't.  This trait spawned the term SARGable (Search Argument - able), and many but not all functions are indeed SARGable.  In this case (on SQL Server) using LEFT() or LIKE 'xxx%' should perform the same.

Comment: @Dems - I've just tried the LEFT approach vs. the LIKE approach, and LEFT isn't treated specially by SQL Server (admittedly 2008 Express as my darned 2008 R2 instance is not playing ball at the moment!).  LEFT -> index scan, LIKE -> index seek.

Answer (score 1):

2k+ entries, yeah, you are probably OK. 2M+ entries and I'd say that you are not OK.  the LEFT function probably won't use an index.  Consider using the `"WHERE name LIKE " + txtboxname.Text + "%"` instead.

problems to consider.

1. Sql injection, you should either
   sanitize the txtboxname.Text or use
   parameterized queries.
2. Indexes usually are used with the LIKE statement as long as the
   '%' is at the begining or the end of
   the statement and not both (ala
   '%sometext%')

Comment: @Al W: I don't think that `LIKE '%sometext'` will use the index.

Comment: Actually, LEFT() can use indexes, as all records would still be in the same order before or after the application of LEFT().  Where as records would be in a fundamentally different order after application of RIGHT().  Therefore, the OPs query is absolutely fine in my opinion.

Comment: For that reason, SQL Server CAN optimise `LIKE 'sometext%'` but CAN'T optimise `LIKE '%sometext'` (as pointed out by ypercube, and so contradicting part of point 2)

Comment: There is workaround though, by adding another index on computed column `REVERSE(field)`.

Comment: @ypercube : would you not need to refactor the query as `REVERSE(field) LIKE 'txetemos%'`?  I don't know, but I'd doubt SQL Server would spot the optimisation without a little coaxing such as this?

Comment: @Dems: exactly, I would write it as `REVERSE(field) LIKE REVERSE('%sometext')`